# Retag or synonym Corruption tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Right now, there are a lot of unnecessary corruption tags.  We have [corruption](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/corruption), [corrupt](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/corrupt), [file-corruption](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/file-corruption) and [data-corruption](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/data-corruption).  Frankly way too many.

Corruption is the most commonly used one, and makes the most sense.  We should synonym or burninate the others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were only 2 [corrupted](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/corrupted), so I manually changed them to [corruption](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/corruption). The other tags contain only a few questions, and I think there's few enough that they can be handled manually.

I'm all for using [corruption](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/corruption) as the correct tag, and since new users can't create new tags until they have 200 rep, I hope simply manually removing the other tags will keep them away for good as the more experienced users seem to recognise you should only create a tag for a good reason.

Comment: Heh, looks like @splattne beat me to the rest of them :-)

Comment: It's a race!!!!

Comment: Yeah, one that I seem to have lost while typing out this answer :P Never mind, all gone now!

Comment: +1 for the manual labor :-)

Comment: @splattne - my general rule of thumb is if there's > 50 questions, ask a mod. Otherwise it can be handled in a few small batches manually.

Comment: @splattne can you take care of the corrupted tag as well?  I'm afraid if it's not synonymed, some wanker will use it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Holocryptic done. Thank you!